# How to create a Jar file for blackberry app for distribution

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have a completed blackberry project how can i create an installable jar file or jad file whichever way its done on blackberry? I'm quite new to this can someone guide me through this please?

I tried exporting the jar file from the deliverables folder in the project but then when I tried installing it on the device it said "Midlet-name attribute missing"..

Comment: Use .jad and .cod files.

Comment: can you explain how to do it please?

Comment: Check this link, How to Deploy and Distribute Applications? http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-to-Deploy-and-Distribute-Applications/ta-p/442794 , read the attached pdf, http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/117/1/How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You may use the .cod file not jar you will find it at the "deliverables" file under your project path.You can use the Java Loader to deploy the app ".cod" in your device.
For More information you may read this 
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/How-to-Deploy-and-Distribute-Applications/ta-p/442794